# Why would you specify an integer as signed in C?

Tags: c, syntax

In my textbook, it says that all integers are considered signed by default, and most of the sources I've found online say that floating point numbers have to be signed, so what's the point of using the `signed` keyword?

Comment: You might use it for `char` variables, which are [not specified to be either signed or unsigned by default](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2054939/is-char-signed-or-unsigned-by-default).

Answer (score 6):

In C, you can omit parts of a typename, so you can actually use `signed` *instead of* `int`, which may look nicely symmetric:

```
void f(signed a, unsigned b);
```

Or more verbosely:

```
unsigned int foo;
signed int bar;
```

If you don't use both types in close vicinity, you would probably prefer the simpler form of the name:

```
int x;   // normal
auto y;  // quaint
signed auto graph;  // why not
```

Answer (score 2):

At least two situations exist where the keyword `unsigned` is needed.

The first one is using the keyword with the type specifier `char` because it can behave either as `signed char` or as `unsigned char`. That is there are three distinct types: `char`, `signed char` and `unsigned char`.

The second one  is using the keyword with bit fields because a bit field with the type specifier `int` can behave either as `signed int` or as `unsigned int`.

Comment: C11 sounds like a plain `int` would not be allowed portably as the type of a bit field (6.7.2.1/5).

Comment: @KerrekSB There is written that "for bitﬁelds, it is implementation-deﬁned whether the speciﬁer int designates the same type as signed int or the same type as unsigned int."

Answer (score 0):

the `signed` word isnt get used so much.
the `unsigned` does because all the integer-types(char is worth-checking)
are self-defined as signed. also, `unsigned float`, `unsigned double` or
`unsigned long double` do not exist.`//signed float/double/long double are errors to.`

Comment: `long double` is valid C.

Comment: yes, but `signed long double` and `unsigned long double` arent